# How to update a line in a text file?

Tags: c#

I want to update a certain part/line in a text file..

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
public static void UpdatingMethod()
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText("fileone.txt");
    text = text.Replace("old value", "new stuff");
    File.WriteAllText("fileone.txt", text);
}

public static void WritingMethod()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {
        Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
        ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write(" Enter your Age: ");
        Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write(" Enter your E-mail: ");
        Email = Console.ReadLine();

        StreamWriter Sw = new StreamWriter("fileone.txt", true);
        string output = string.Format("Thank you for registration! Your Submitted information are:" + Environment.NewLine + "Name: {0}"
        + Environment.NewLine + "ID: {1}" + Environment.NewLine + "Age: {2}" + Environment.NewLine + "E-mail: {3}", Name, ID, Age, Email);           
        Console.WriteLine(output);      
        Sw.WriteLine(output + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Sw.Close();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I call the method, the cmd opens and close automatically without displaying anything!

Comment: What are you expecting to be displayed?  You don't write anything to the console here.

Comment: It seems to work OK... Do you get some error/exception?

Comment: I just copied the update method code here. Wait a moment I will edit the post with the full code. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Don't post the full code.  Just post enough for someone to recreate the issue.

Comment: Okay, I updated the post now. Take a look on it. Thanks Again :) 
and by the way the text file not empty.

Comment: Where do you call these methods?

Comment: Where is the Update method called?

Comment: In a separate class called "caller.cs"

Comment: How about you just post the relevant code in `Main`?  `WritingMethod` is irrelevant here.

Comment: I have two separate classes "allmethods.cs" that contains all methods and "caller.cs" where I call methods inside it.

Comment: How do you expect this to work?

Comment: -1. Please don't say 'Doesn't work' without providing details of what actually happens, and what you want to happen.

Comment: When I call the method, the cmd opens and close automatically without displaying anything! .. I want data to be displayed in the cmd and to be able to do updates on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a main method that is used as an entry point to you application.

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // not really good names for what it's worth
        WritingMethod();
        UpdatingMethod();
    }
}
```

[MSDN Main() & Command Line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)